# How to develop transparent interface?

Tags: netbeans, photoshop

This is not completely a programming question. Today when I load LiLi USB creator software I saw the interfaces are transparent. Is that because they are Photoshopped or is transparency a technique of IDE? I'm using both NetbBeans and Eclipse. To be clear, I'm adding a photo too.

[image: **Full Picture**]

[image: **Flower Part**]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For transparency of the entire GUI, including controls (which doesn't seem to be the case in your screenshot), .NET includes the [`Form.Opacity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.opacity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

Additionally, it may be possible to use [`LayeredWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.osfeature.layeredwindows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to change only the opacity of the top-level component to produce the desired effect.

For Java specifically, there's [an official Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html) for that, although it seems to set the opacity of the entire window, including all child components.

Comment: Can you please be kindly enough to answer another question.. We can make rectangled and corner curved rectangled interfaces using netbeans and photoshop. But Still how can we manage to add that flower type part to the interface. Please explain it. I added that part specially to understand to you as another picture..

Comment: I mean obviously we can design any part using photoshop, Still how come that photo's shape add to interface in IDE